# Posting Poetry by Deceased Persons

Tags: publishing, copyright

Do I have a legal right to post poetry on FB from my deceased grandmother's journal, written by others now deceased, in the 1920's, which includes their names and addresses? The journal was given to me by my mother, also deceased.

Answer (score 2):

In the United States, the Copyright Act of 1977 asserts that the copyright of works written by people who died in the 1920s expired in the 1990s. That means the works are in the public domain and you can post them to Facebook without infringing on the rights of the heirs -- which I assume would be your mother and her siblings.

Since you suggest the poetry is written by many authors, if you wanted to know precisely when their copyright expired then you would have to determine when the last writer died and add 70 years. It's a moot point but some people are persnickety like that.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that even were it in copyright, she would have been been one of the heirs.  Perhaps the only one.  The question would be then who are the others with a claim and how to negotiate it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where your grandmother lived and where the other authors lived, so I'll give a more general answer. According to the Berne Convention, a work is copyrighted until 50 years after the author's death. Many countries have extended this copyright term, among them the United States (70 years), Guinea (80), Ivory Coast (99), and Mexico (100). Here is a list of copyright durations by country: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries%27_copyright_lengths

If you want to publish any of the poems in your grandmother's journal, you have to find out the date of each author's death and the duration of copyright protection for their jurisdiction.

If for example, one of the authors was 20 years old when they wrote the poem in 1920, they could well have lived until 1990. If they had lived in the United States, their poems would then be protected until 2060. If they had been Mexican, their poems would be protected until 2090.

If your grandmother has written any poems herself and her own poems are still protected by copyright, you will have to get the permission of all her heirs, that is, all her children and, if any of the children are no longer alive, the respective grandchildren.